# How can we record conversation with a web app bot Azure deployed on Teams?

Tags: azure, bots, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have deployed a web app bot on Azure for my team on the channel Microsoft teams. I would like to record all conversations of the bot. What are the available options or resources where we can store conversations with users?
The goal is to evaluate the good answers/responses rate from the chatbot.

Thanks

Comment: I think you would like to store your bot conversations to analyze them later for quality. The available options in this scenario are Azure blobs or cosmos db with minimal configuration changes to your existing bot. If your use case is to provide a Q&A to users then you might want to use Azure QnAMaker instead and create a knowledge base and publish a bot from this service. This allows you to use QnAMaker's inbuilt active learning feature and improve your bot's response by approving or rejecting alternate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Moving comments to answer section for better visibility.

I think you would like to store your bot conversations to analyze them later for quality. The available options in this scenario are Azure blobs or cosmos db with minimal configuration changes to your existing bot. If your use case is to provide a Q&A to users then you might want to use Azure QnAMaker instead and create a knowledge base and publish a bot from this service. This allows you to use QnAMaker's inbuilt active learning feature and improve your bot's response by approving or rejecting alternate suggestions.